# How can I get Glimpse to work with EF6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, glimpse

**EDIT**: stack trace added at bottom.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project that uses a SQL Server database via Entity Framework 6.

I added Glimpse (and Glimpse.MVC5) to the project, and that works fine.

However, when I add Glimpse.EF6, my application throws an exception as soon as it attempts to access the database. The exception is:

**`System.NotSupportedException`**

> Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.

What's going on? FYI, the `connectionStrings` part of my web.config looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=foo; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

...and my `Application_Start` method looks like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    Database.SetInitializer(new WebApplication.Models.Storage.ApplicationDbInitializer());
}
```

...and my context class looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help...

---

**STACK TRACE:**

```
[NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.]
System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderFactoryExtensions.GetProviderInvariantName(DbProviderFactory factory) +290
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultInvariantNameResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +248
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 k) +75
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +210
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r) +60
System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +66
System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +161
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key) +250
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +106
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r) +60
System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +66
System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +94
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key) +250
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key) +102
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService(IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Object key) +145
System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.<>c__DisplayClass5.<GetExecutionStrategy>b__4(ExecutionStrategyKey k) +84
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetExecutionStrategy(DbConnection connection, DbProviderFactory providerFactory) +351
System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetExecutionStrategy(DbConnection connection) +62
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +319
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +335
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +399
System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +132

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +327
Glimpse.EF.AlternateType.GlimpseDbProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +113
System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +255
System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +67

[ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure.]
System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) +277
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ResolveManifestToken>b__0(Tuple`3 k) +63
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +360
System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +89
System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +79
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +143
System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +171
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +594
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +31
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +39
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +138
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path) +41
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) +142
System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, String path) +205
System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 path) +305
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.GetUserAggregateAsync(Expression`1 filter) +610
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.FindByNameAsync(String userName) +1070
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindByNameAsync>d__10.MoveNext() +283
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() +24
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindAsync>d__18.MoveNext() +673
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +24
WebApplication.Controllers.<Login>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Gary\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\eByGum\WebApplication\Controllers\AccountController.cs:49
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +21
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task) +61
System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +114
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +66
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
Castle.Proxies.AsyncControllerActionInvokerProxy.EndInvokeActionMethod_callback(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
Castle.Proxies.Invocations.AsyncControllerActionInvoker_EndInvokeActionMethod.InvokeMethodOnTarget() +103
Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +117
Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.CastleInvocationToAlternateMethodContextAdapter.Proceed() +48
Glimpse.Mvc.AlternateType.EndInvokeActionMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context) +152
Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateTypeToCastleInterceptorAdapter.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) +183
Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +483
Castle.Proxies.AsyncControllerActionInvokerProxy.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +203
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +117
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41() +323
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514812
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Could you add a stacktrace? Or even better, create an issue on [our issue tracker](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues) because this  doesn't sound like something you did wrong. Just as a quick check, do you have the same issue when you put the Database.SetInitializer in comments?

Comment: @cgijbels:Removing the Database.SetInitializer made no difference. I'll add the stacktrace and create an issue.

Comment: @cgijbels: added as [issue 173](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/713). Thanks.

Comment: There are currently several issues related to EF6 and Glimpse. Best to report them on the Glipse issues list on github.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those of you looking for a workaround:

It looks like it's a [bug within EF itself](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/713) (it was mentioned as 173 above, but the link is correct).  You can either wait for EF 6.1.1/6.2 or you can downgrade to EF 6.0.2 and it will start to work again.

In the Package Manager Console, type this:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.0.2
```

and you should be good to go.

But only if EF 6.0.2 is an option for you.   Good luck.

Comment: Rolling back to 6.0.2 won't help those that are using Identity 2.0

Comment: Correct - thank you for pointing that out @ScottE.  Hopefully the next version of EF comes out quickly and resolves this.

Comment: I've rolled back to 6.0.2 and still having an issue..

Did anyone get it sorted?

Answer (score 1):

In case of having problem like Eric Sassaman had, working with Glimpse and seems to hosed your project. Make sure after glimpse remove (from nuget) you've removed all dll's from the bin directory. 
In my case, Azure build was caching glimpse dll's which made an error like:
`[NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.]`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below to your config file

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>    
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I already had something similar (I did not show the whole of my web.config file - only the `connectionStrings` element), but interestingly my `defaultConnectionFactory` was set to the local db provider. Anyway, I changed it to be the same as you suggested, and unfortunately it made no difference - I still get the same error.

Comment: Also, I should add, when I remove Glimpse.EF6, all my database access works fine. It seems to be when I add Glimpse.EF6 that it all goes wrong.

Comment: Wow, installing Glimpse.EF6 seems to have permanently hosed my project, I can't get rid of this error even after uninstalling Glimpse completely. I was forced to restore the entire project from a backup!

Comment: Installing EF from Nuget places the above mentioned config section into the config file. So, while you should check it's there, it's not likely to be the problem if you installed from Nuget.