# Glimpse.EF.AlternateType.GlimpseDbProviderServices' not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, glimpse

- VS2013 Update 2

I am getting the following error:

```
Constructor on type 'Glimpse.EF.AlternateType.GlimpseDbProviderServices' not found.
```

After following advice on [How can I get Glimpse to work with EF6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333863/how-can-i-get-glimpse-to-work-with-ef6) I downgraded EF to 6.02 (from 6.1.1) but am still getting the error. I have also ensured that I no longer hvae Glimpse referenced anywhere in the solution.

Is there another work around to get my project to run up?

**EDIT**

Added stack trace for what it is worth:

```
[MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'Glimpse.EF.AlternateType.GlimpseDbProviderServices' not found.]
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1136
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +128
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +19
   Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbProviderFactory`1.GetService(Type serviceType) +382
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderServices(DbProviderFactory factory) +149
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderServices(DbConnection connection) +14
   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.GetStorageMetadata(String providerName, DbConnection connection, String ssdl) +66
   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMetadataWorkspace(String providerName, DbConnection connection, String csdl, String ssdl, String msl) +246
   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateEntityConnection(ConnectionStringSettings setting, String csdl, String ssdl, String msl) +198
   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMembershipEntities(ConnectionStringSettings setting) +82
   System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider.RoleExists(String roleName) +138
   System.Web.Security.Roles.RoleExists(String roleName) +56
   XXXX.Common.Helpers.Security.SecurityHelper.RegisterRoles() in e:\xxxxxx\SecurityHelper.cs:82
   XXXX.Platform.Global.Application_Start(Object aSender, EventArgs aEventArgs) in e:\xxxxxx\Global.asax.cs:60

[HttpException (0x80004005): Constructor on type 'Glimpse.EF.AlternateType.GlimpseDbProviderServices' not found.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9936761
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Constructor on type 'Glimpse.EF.AlternateType.GlimpseDbProviderServices' not found.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9915300
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Comment: Has anyone got any insight here? I am still dead in the water.

Comment: Followed up within github as an issue - https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/474#issuecomment-47049380

Comment: Did you get any closer with a resolution on this?

Comment: @RichardSimpson No I did not get anywhere. I ultimately stripped Glimpse out of the project and have not come back to look at it again as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Glimpse dlls from the BIN folder .